# How can I use arrow keys to navigate in console app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console, std

I'm practicing `std::cout` & `std::cin`. I would like to `std::cout` Three strings on new lines (e.g.)

Person 1 :
Person 2 :
Person 3 :

and have them all display as well as take inputs (e.g.)

Person 1 : `std::cin`
Person 2 : `std::cin`
Person 3 : `std::cin`

and then use arrow keys to navigate to the inputs. Then clear screen and `std::cout` results. I tried this but it prints one line and accepts one input at a time.

```
std::cout << "Enter the amount of pancakes ate by each person" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Person 1 : ";
    std::cin >> amount1;
    std::cout << "Person 2 : ";
    std::cin >> amount2;
    std::cout << "Person 3 : ";
    std::cin >> amount3;
```

Any help or resource that explains this UI capability?

Comment: There is no standard way to process special keys and console output in C++.  Refer to your OS and the OS API's that handle console input / output (for example, the Windows Console API).

Comment: You can use a [curses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie unfortunately that's probably the route I'd have to go. Thanks, I was just hoping there was a way using c++ libs.